# error C2065: done: необьявленный идентификатор

Tags: visual-studio, c++

Только начал изучать Visual C++ 2010 вот по таким урокам: [Игра "Угадай число"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dKr28WtDX9E) и столкнулся с проблемой.
Вот исходник программы (делал все как на видео)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <clocale>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale (LC_CTYPE,"Russian");   
    srand (time (0)); 
    do {
        bool done; 
        int i = rand() % 100;
        while (true) {
            cout << "Я загадал число, теперь угадай";   
            int j;
            cin >> j;
            if (i > j)
                cout << "бери больше" << endl;
            else { 
                if (i < j)
                    cout << "бери меньше" << endl;
                else {
                    cout << "Ты угадал" << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
       }
       cout << "продолжить? (y/n)" << endl;
       char c;
       cin >> c;
       done = (c != 'y');
   } while (!done);
}
```

Не компилируется, выбивает ошибку.

> error C2065: done: необьявленный идентификатор

как исправить и что не так делаю?

Comment: Смените компилятор (например на g++), который нормально пишет *какой именно идентификатор и в какой строке* не объявлен.

Comment: так там же сказано, что неизвестный идентификатор называется done. А найти строку ошибки можно, кликнув по сообщению дважды

Comment: @Taktik Вынесите объявление переменной done выше. Вы её объявляете в теле do-while, а используете в условии while.

@avp Мне приходилось сталкиваться с VS6 (и, кажется, VS7). VS6 меня в своё время поразил до глубины души. Текст сообщения около 1000 символов, VS его делит на две строки по полтысячи, а в окне я вижу сотни полторы из первой половины и столько же из второй. И скроллер. Можно посмотреть 1ю и 4ю шестую часть, 2ю и 5ю, 3ю и 6ю. Мелкими буквами по-аглицки. Пока сообщение не скопируешь куда-нибудь, прочитать не получается. Очень интересное решение.

Answer (score 1):

У вас переменная `done` объявлена внутри цикла, а используете вы ее снаружи (при проверке условия выхода из цикла) Разумеется, компилятор понятия не имеет о том, что вы  имеете в виду внутреннюю переменную. 
З.Ы. найдите нормальную книгу по С++, а не это видеобарахло, что вы смотрите (да, понимаю, читать лень, но что поделаешь)

Comment: спасибо розобрался уже что к чему

Comment: @Taktik Подумайте о стратегии. Позиция "я на вас плевал" -- не самая лучшая, если Вы собираетесь задавать ещё вопросы. Если это не Ваша позиция -- закройте вопрос.